# ui_component form state/region field update after country select (M 2.1)

Tags: grid, magento-2.1, uicomponent, country-regions

I created form as a ui_component in my module. It has all data which is neccesary -> country list and region/state list.

The only problem is the region field doesn`t update on country change. It always display dropdown with all provided states. So if I choose United States as a "country" it should display only US states in region/state field but it always displays all.

XML with form:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">testModule_localstores_localstore_form.localstore_form_data_source</item>
            <item name="deps" xsi:type="string">testModule_localstores_localstore_form.localstore_form_data_source</item>
        </item>
        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">General Information</item>
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">data</item>
            <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">testModule_localstores_localstore_form</item>
        </item>
        <item name="template" xsi:type="string">templates/form/collapsible</item>
        <item name="buttons" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="back" xsi:type="string">testModule\LocalStores\Block\Adminhtml\LocalStore\Edit\BackButton</item>
            <item name="delete" xsi:type="string">testModule\LocalStores\Block\Adminhtml\LocalStore\Edit\DeleteButton</item>
            <item name="reset" xsi:type="string">testModule\LocalStores\Block\Adminhtml\LocalStore\Edit\ResetButton</item>
            <item name="save" xsi:type="string">testModule\LocalStores\Block\Adminhtml\LocalStore\Edit\SaveButton</item>
            <item name="save_and_continue" xsi:type="string">testModule\LocalStores\Block\Adminhtml\LocalStore\Edit\SaveAndContinueButton</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
    <dataSource name="localstore_form_data_source">
        <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
            <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">testModule\LocalStores\Model\LocalStore\DataProvider</argument>
            <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">localstore_form_data_source</argument>
            <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">localstore_id</argument>
            <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">localstore_id</argument>
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="submit_url" xsi:type="url" path="testModule_localstores/localstore/save"/>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </argument>
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/provider</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </dataSource>
    <fieldset name="localstore">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string"/>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <field name="localstore_id">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">localstore</item>
                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">localstore_id</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
        <field name="name">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Name</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">localstore</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">20</item>
                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">name</item>
                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
        <field name="address">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Address</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">localstore</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">30</item>
                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">address</item>
                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
        <field name="city">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">City</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">localstore</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">40</item>
                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">city</item>
                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
        <field name="zip">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">zip</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Zip</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">localstore</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">50</item>
                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">zip</item>
                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
        <field name="country">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Country</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">60</item>
                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">country</item>
                </item>
                <item name="options" xsi:type="object">Magento\Directory\Model\Config\Source\Country</item>
            </argument>
        </field>
        <field name="region_id">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Region Id</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">localstore</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">70</item>
                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">region_id</item>
                </item>
                <item name="options" xsi:type="object">Magento\Directory\Model\ResourceModel\Region\Collection</item>
            </argument>
            <argument name="default_filter" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="country" xsi:type="string"></item>
            </argument>
        </field>
        <field name="region">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Region</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">localstore</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">80</item>
                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">region</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Formatted version: http://pastebin.com/fB4045zt

Answer (score 4):

Tested working code with country/region fields dependency:

```
<fieldset name="address">
...
<field name="country_id">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="options" xsi:type="object">Magento\Directory\Model\ResourceModel\Country\Collection</item>
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Country</item>
                <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">100</item>
                <item name="source" xsi:type="string">address</item><!-- fieldset name -->
                <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">country</item><!-- 'country' - db table column name where country code is saved --> 
                <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </field>
    <field name="region_id">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="options" xsi:type="object">Magento\Directory\Model\ResourceModel\Region\Collection</item>
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">State/Province</item>
                <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">110</item>
                <item name="source" xsi:type="string">address</item><!-- fieldset name -->
                <item name="customEntry" xsi:type="string">state_province</item><!-- 'state_province' - db table column name where region name is saved -->
                <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">state_province_id</item><!-- 'state_province_id' - db table column name where region id is saved -->
                <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                </item>
                <item name="filterBy" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="target" xsi:type="string">${ $.provider }:${ $.parentScope }.country</item><!-- 'country' - db table column name where country code is saved -->
                    <item name="field" xsi:type="string">country_id</item><!-- country_id field name -->
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </field>
    <field name="region">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">State/Province</item>
                <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">115</item>
                <item name="source" xsi:type="string">address</item><!-- fieldset name -->
                <item name="customEntry" xsi:type="string">state_province</item><!-- 'state_province' - db table column name where region name is saved -->
                <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">state_province</item><!-- 'state_province' - db table column name where region name is saved -->
                <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </field>
...
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 1):

Working example of country / region fields with region properly filtering based on country selection.

OP: Anthony Charrex
[Issue with country and region field in custom module using ui-component](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/152738/issue-with-country-and-region-field-in-custom-module-using-ui-component)

```
<field name="country_id">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="options" xsi:type="object">Magento\Directory\Model\Config\Source\Country</item>
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Country</item>
            <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">select</item>
            <item name="source" xsi:type="string">store</item>
            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/element/country</item>
            <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</field>
<field name="region">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">State/Region</item>
            <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
            <item name="source" xsi:type="string">store</item>
            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">15</item>
            <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</field>
<field name="region_id">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="options" xsi:type="object">Magento\Directory\Model\ResourceModel\Region\Collection</item>
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">State/Region</item>
            <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">select</item>
            <item name="source" xsi:type="string">store</item>
            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">20</item>
            <item name="customEntry" xsi:type="string">region</item>
            <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            </item>
            <item name="filterBy" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="target" xsi:type="string">${ $.provider }:${ $.parentScope }.country_id</item>
                <item name="field" xsi:type="string">country_id</item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</field>
```

Comment: What is the use of <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/element/country</item>

Comment: I want to use custom tables to populate in  my custom form. I followed the same pattern as country and region but it is not working

Comment: Simple and workable solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can see an example here:

> vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/layout/checkout_cart_index.xml

```
<item name="region_id" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/element/region</item>
    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">112</item>
    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/form/field</item>
        <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/form/element/select</item>
        <item name="customEntry" xsi:type="string">shippingAddress.region</item>
    </item>
    <!-- Value of region_id field is filtered by the value of county_id attribute -->
    <item name="filterBy" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="target" xsi:type="string"><![CDATA[${ $.provider }:${ $.parentScope }.country_id]]></item>
        <item name="field" xsi:type="string">country_id</item>
    </item>
</item>
```

You should add the default filter to the region id field.

Comment: I have two tables city and region and want to to update region on base of city I did the model collection and xml but region is not updating any help please

Comment: @AbdulBasit Could you ask own question where you can write code you are using? I'll try to help you, but without the code you are using its hard to explain something.

Comment: I have posted the question here https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/199102/magento2-dependent-select-fields-filtering

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/199102/magento2-dependent-select-fields-filtering

Comment: how can we show the region label instead of region id in admin grid? please help me

Comment: @Afreen Please, ask this as a different question, give me a link and I'll try to help you.

Comment: @SiarheyUchukhlebau can you please give me short details of filterBy's target and field attribute? On which basis should I need to set value in both field in custom dropdowns?

Comment: Can you pls help me here? https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/294983/51810