# Issue with country and region field in custom module using ui-component

Tags: admin, uicomponent, magento-2.1.3

I am trying to add country and region fields in my custom module in admin section. I have managed to populate the country field values, but while selecting country, unable to get the regions.

This is my xml code :

```
<field name="country_id">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="options" xsi:type="object">Magento\Directory\Model\Config\Source\Country</item>
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Country</item>
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/element/country</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">address</item>
                    <!--<item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">country_id</item>-->
                    <item name="imports" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="default" xsi:type="string">${ $.provider }:data.customer.website_id</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>

         <field name="region">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">address</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>

        <field name="region_id">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">address</item>
                    <item name="customEntry" xsi:type="string">region</item>
                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="filterBy" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="target" xsi:type="string">${ $.provider }:${ $.parentScope }.country_id</item>
                        <item name="field" xsi:type="string">country_id</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
```

Let me know where I am wrong or if anything is missing here...

Any help  would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution:

```
<field name="country_id">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="options" xsi:type="object">Magento\Directory\Model\Config\Source\Country</item>
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Country</item>
            <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">select</item>
            <item name="source" xsi:type="string">store</item>
            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/element/country</item>
            <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</field>
<field name="region">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">State/Region</item>
            <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
            <item name="source" xsi:type="string">store</item>
            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">15</item>
            <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</field>
<field name="region_id">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="options" xsi:type="object">Magento\Directory\Model\ResourceModel\Region\Collection</item>
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">State/Region</item>
            <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">select</item>
            <item name="source" xsi:type="string">store</item>
            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">20</item>
            <item name="customEntry" xsi:type="string">region</item>
            <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            </item>
            <item name="filterBy" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="target" xsi:type="string">${ $.provider }:${ $.parentScope }.country_id</item>
                <item name="field" xsi:type="string">country_id</item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</field>
```

Anthony