# Magento 2 : How to Use County and Region dropdown in custom module

Tags: magento-2.1, adminform, country-regions

I have a simple question about handling Country and Region dropdowns in admin form. 
Do I need to create two EAV attributes for region and region_id and put dropdown value in region_id and custom region value in region field.
Can't I use the same attribute, some how.
Is there a good tutorial which handles the scenario.

Comment: I believe you should take a look into: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/181621

Comment: I already did this. This gives me form UI. I am confused on database end, should i have 2 attribute "region_id" and "region" or I can do with single one.?

Comment: yes you should create two field in database region_id & state. region_id holds id for that region & state hold state code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok
I created two attributes region and region_id.
In region goes the region name for the countries where we don't have list available and in region_id goes the value of regions select box.
I also had to make some changes in Save method to clear values if we edited the field `if($data['region_id']){$data['region']=NULL;}`. Also had to add attribute in database.