# In Magento2 For Ui component Form select Field,Dependency with another Field

Tags: magento2, uicomponent, dependency

On Magento2 For UI Component Form select Field should be having dependency on another value on the selection on ex: IF there is Field name: Field1 dropdown on selecting option then it should display a field below A Field2 related to This collection As show in the below screenshot

Screenshot:

[image]

Thanks in advance Please Help me.

Comment: Hello Brother @AshishRaj My question is not same as that,Please read the lines.i need to show on selecting First option should display That child Options for First Option Label related Collection.You cannot just put question as duplicate.ok

Comment: Ok Dont worry...
This can be resolved by the link: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/134002/ui-component-form-state-region-field-update-after-country-select-m-2-1
So can be considered as duplicate of this but we must do some research and search before post new question... I have faced this kind of problem so I am suggesting you